# Maven assembly - creating zip of zips

Tags: maven, plugins, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

How do I use Maven assembly to create zip of zips and install the zip containing other zips?

For example, I need to create A.zip, B.zip, C.zip and finally have something D.zip (containing A, B and C) to be installed.

When I have something as below, what happens is that Maven created all of them A, B, C and D zip files, but it installs a zip randomly (in the sense it installs B.zip whereas I wanted to have D.zip to be installed).

Any advice how to get around the issue?

```
<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>A</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>                        
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>B</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>                        
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>C</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>                        
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>D</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>                        
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

Comment: How did you call maven? mvn clean package ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put the a, b and c into prepare-package phase instead of the package phase whereas the D will be left in the package phase. You have to change the configuration for A, B and C like the following:

```
<execution>
  <id>A</id>
  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>single</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <attach>false</attach>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Leave the configuration for D untouched.